# How do I add an on-click event to a line rendered with the LineRenderer component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Implement line renderer with click

I am new to Unity. I am implementing a project where I need to create lines based on coordinates. I have already done this, but I also have to be able to click on that line to execute a script. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a bit to get to the core of the problem more clearly. Someone else will probably vote to close this question because you have not demonstrated any attempt to solve this problem on your own. When asking questions on here you don't need to have greetings, or sign-offs like an email. I suggest you check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not supported by the default `LineRenderer` component.

A way to do this would be to generate a `2D Polygon Collider` programmatically based on the points used to draw your line.

You could do this by taking the width of the line, and determining the directional vector towards the next line point. At each point, you would take the perpendicular direction from the directional vector in both the 'up' and 'down' (aka just multiply the perpendicular vector by `-1`}, and then add those two new points to your `Polygon Collider`. With just two line points, that would form a rectangular collider. You can then write a script that allows you to 'click' on that rectangle using `Raycasts` from the Camera view.

Beware that the `2D Polygon Collider` may require those points to appear in a certain order, meaning that it is possible you'd have to 'loop around' your entire line, aka taking all the positive perpendicular values first, starting from the start of your line to the end of your line, and then all the negative perpendicular values, starting at the end and moving to the start.

Also beware that this method may cause certain accuracy issues at sharp corners. If you want 100% accuracy, you may have to clean up the resulting point data.